# Adding out of stock to product card grid page

Tags: shopify

I am trying to apply the [following "out of stock" code](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/forms/add-product-availability-reminder-form) to the **product-card-grid.liquid** page but it seems to only be working for one item, ie a single listing on the **product-template.liquid**, instead of all. I think this is because the referenced implementation is only for one page and not for multiple item listings. How do I update it so that this isn't the case?

```
<div class="grid-view-item{% unless product.available %} product-price--sold-out grid-view-item--sold-out{% endunless %}">
  <a class="grid-view-item__link grid-view-item__image-container" href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">
    {% capture img_id %}ProductCardImage-{{ section.id }}-{{ product.id }}{% endcapture %}
    {% capture wrapper_id %}ProductCardImageWrapper-{{ section.id }}-{{ product.id }}{% endcapture %}
    {%- assign img_url = product.featured_image | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' -%}

    {% unless product.featured_image == blank %}
      {% include 'image-style' with image: product.featured_image, width: max_height, height: max_height, small_style: true, wrapper_id: wrapper_id, img_id: img_id %}
    {% endunless %}

    <div id="{{ wrapper_id }}" class="grid-view-item__image-wrapper js">
      <div style="padding-top:{% unless product.featured_image == blank %}{{ 1 | divided_by: product.featured_image.aspect_ratio | times: 100}}%{% else %}100%{% endunless %};">
        <img id="{{ img_id }}"
             class="grid-view-item__image lazyload"
             src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: '300x300' }}"
             data-src="{{ img_url }}"
             data-widths="[180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048]"
             data-aspectratio="{{ product.featured_image.aspect_ratio }}"
             data-sizes="auto"
             alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
      </div>
    </div>

    <noscript>
      {% capture image_size %}{{ max_height }}x{{ max_height }}{% endcapture %}
      <img class="grid-view-item__image" src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: image_size, scale: 2 }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt }}" style="max-width: {{ max_height | times: product.featured_image.aspect_ratio }}px;">
    </noscript>

    <div class="h4 grid-view-item__title">{{ product.title }}</div>
    {% if section.settings.show_vendor %}
      <div class="grid-view-item__vendor">{{ product.vendor }}</div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="grid-view-item__meta">
      {% include 'product-price' %}
    </div>

    {% unless product.available %}
    <div id="sold-out" style="margin-top: 10px">
      {% form 'contact' %}
        {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
        <p class="accent-text">Thanks! We will notify you when this product becomes available!</p>
        {% else %}
        <p><a id="notify-me" class="product-page-notify-me" href="#" style="color: #788188;">Email me when available</a></p>
        {% endif %}
        {% if form.errors %}
        <div class="error feedback accent-text">
          <p>Please provide a valid email address.</p>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% unless form.posted_successfully? %}
        <div id="notify-me-wrapper" class="clearfix" style="display:none">
          {% if customer %}
          <input type="hidden" name="contact[email]" value="{{ customer.email }}" />
          {% else %}
          <input style="float:left; width:100%;" required="required" type="email" name="contact[email]" placeholder="your@email.com" class="styled-input{% if form.errors contains 'email' %} error{% endif %}" value="{{ contact.fields.email }}" />
          {% endif %}
          <input type="hidden" name="contact[body]" value="Please notify me when {{ product.title | escape }} becomes available." />
          <input style="float:left;" class="btn styled-submit" type="submit" value="Send" />         
        </div>
        {% endunless %}
      {% endform %}
    </div>
    {% endunless %}

  </a>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried editing the jQuery as follows, which fixes it but the submit button sends an email for all the items on the product listing page:

jQuery('.notify-me').click(function() {
  jQuery($(this).closest('.contact-form').find('.notify-me-wrapper').fadeIn());
  return false;
});

Comment: Did you update the JS so that it doesn't target the global ID element, but it's limited to the "this" scope of the clicked element?

Comment: No I haven't. That's a good idea actually. Let me try